# Двойные кнопки - так и должно быть или что-то неверно?

Tags: html, css, share

Здравствуйте! Установила кнопки на статьи. И смущает их внешний вид, они как будто двойные, скриншот высылаю. Всмысле двоится буква/картинка. Заранее благодарю.
Может, я что-то не так сделала?
http://ovrazhnaya-4.ru/blog/?p=6
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можно код css?

Comment: А вы можете код со стороннего сайта перенести сюда?

Answer (score 4):

В style.css код

```
.emm-paginate a, span {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

добавляет кнопкам padding, из-за чего их размер становиться больше и благодаря повторению фона он "двоится". Добавьте в css код

```
span.ya-share2__icon {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю такое решение: у вас размер фона меньше чем размер кнопки и чтобы фон не двоился, нужно установить такой стиль:

```
.ya-share2__icon {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.ya-share2__icon {
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 50%;
}
```